# Label Number of Occurrence

Tags: sql

I have data similar to this:

```
    a | "Random String"
    b | "Random String"
    b | "Random String"
    c | "Random String"
    d | "Random String"
    d | "Random String"
    d | "Random String"
    a | "Random String"
```

I want to label the data based on the number of occurrences of the letter column:

```
    1 | a | "Random String"
    1 | b | "Random String"
    2 | b | "Random String"
    1 | c | "Random String"
    1 | d | "Random String"
    2 | d | "Random String"
    3 | d | "Random String"
    2 | a | "Random String"
```

Comment: You can use analytical functions for that, using `OVER` and `PARTITION BY`. If you tag which dbms you are using you can get a more specific answer.

Comment: is the value in 2nd column `Random String` always the same?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ANSI standard `row_number()`, which most databases support:

```
select row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1), col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Without row_number():

```
SELECT 
(SELECT 1+COUNT(letter) 
    FROM TableName WHERE id < tn.id AND letter = tn.letter) AS occurrences,    
tn.letter,
tn.random_string
FROM TableName tn
```